# Put a fixed title in an interactive 3D plot using rgl package, R

Tags: r, plot, title, interactive, rgl

I am trying to add a fixed title to an interactive 3d plot using the rgl package from R, but so far I haven't been able to do it. I also would like to have one main title and a subtitle under the main title.

Here is a sample code,

```
library(rgl)

data<-read.table(text="          X         Y         Z
                 1  147.0883 -18.69122 -13.90000
                 2  147.0894 -18.69455 -10.97250
                 3  147.0883 -18.69122 -17.45000
                 4  147.0883 -18.69122 -15.44000
                 5  147.0883 -18.69122 -13.45000
                 6  147.0909 -18.69922 -12.25000
                 7  147.0883 -18.69122 -17.30000
                 8  147.0883 -18.69122 -16.40000
                 9  147.0883 -18.69122 -14.30000
                 10 147.0883 -18.69122 -18.50000
                 11 147.0883 -18.69122 -15.67606
                 12 147.0883 -18.69122 -17.25780
                 13 147.0883 -18.69122  -3.64000
                 14 147.1164 -18.68133 -22.13000
                 15 147.0883 -18.69122 -18.54778
                 16 147.0883 -18.69122 -15.50000
                 17 147.1185 -18.68691 -14.55500
                 18 147.0883 -18.69122 -18.12500
                 19 147.0901 -18.69670 -14.39767",header=T)

data

a<-as.matrix(data)

# call the plug-in bandwidth estimator 
H.pi<-Hpi(a,binned=TRUE)*3 ## a is a matrix of x,y,z points 

# calculate the kernel densities 
fhat<-kde(a,H=H.pi)

# produce a 3D plot
open3d()

title<-"Individual 1 (male)" # main title
title2<-"Site A" # subtitle

plot(fhat,cont=c(50,95),colors=c("green","red"),drawpoints=TRUE,
     xlab="",ylab="", zlab="",size=1.5,ptcol="black", 
     axes=F,box=T,aspect=c(1,1,0.5),zlim=c(-40,0))

axes3d(c("x--","y--","z-+"),cex=0.8)
mtext3d("Longitude",edge="x--",line=3,las=2,cex=1.1)
mtext3d("Latitude",edge="y--",line=3,las=2,cex=1.1)
mtext3d("Depth (m)",edge="z-+",line=3,las=2,cex=1.1)

title3d(main=title,sub=title2,line=4)
```

I haven't found a good way of having a fixed title (and subtitle) so that when I export my plot as a 3D movie, the main title is not rotating with the plot...

```
movie3d(spin3d(axis=c(0,0,1), rpm=4),dir="~/Dropbox/R/Sample plots", duration=15, fps=10, movie="Plot 1")
```

If you have a good/easy way of putting the main title in a fixed location (and possibly adding a secondary title under) that will be great. Thanks in advance,

Comment: I think what you want is not possible with `rgl`.  You might consider adding the title after you create the movie using some other software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cannot be done in rgl at present.

Comment: Is there a way to have at least the main title at a fixed location in the background while the plot is moving?

Comment: No - ?rgl.texts says the text is positioned in 3d space, facing the user. The rgl graphics device doesn't use the standard R plotting system so `text` won't work, `title` won't work etc. I think it just needs some work at the C++ level to implement 2d static text using the ftgl library that rgl uses for its text.

Answer (score 16):

**Putting a title in a RGL plot is now possible**, thanks to an update dating from last year.

The idea is to use the new function `bgplot3d` which outputs to the background of the RGL window, as if it was a normal plot.

For example:

```
# A minimal plot3d example
library(rgl)
a = matrix(runif(3000), ncol=3)
plot3d(a, col = rainbow(100)[cut(a[,1], breaks = seq(0,1,le=101), include.lowest = T)])

bgplot3d({
  plot.new()
  title(main = 'This is the main title', line = 3)
  mtext(side = 1, 'This is a subtitle', line = 4)
  # use here any other way you fancy to write your title
})
```

Which gives:

[image: RGL title with plot3d and bgplot3d]

There is one pretty important caveat though, stated as a note in the help page for `bgplot3d`:

> Because the background plots are drawn as bitmaps, they do not resize
>   very gracefully. It's best to size your window first, then draw the
>   background at that size.

Answer (score 1):

To reproduce your script kde is missing (a library not included) ... in any case
Did you consider using:adding after the movie:

```
text3d(x=0.08, y=0.97, z=0.03, title.main ,col="Blue")
```

where: x,y,z are locations in your graphic. I have use this together with scatter3d (using also using rgl).

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the suggestion about test, you can add a legend that stays stationary and use it as your title. See example below from [Adding a legend to an rgl 3d plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27958226/adding-a-legend-to-an-rgl-3d-plot)

```
legend3d("topright", legend = paste('Type', c('A', 'B', 'C')), pch = 16, col = rainbow(3), cex=1, inset=c(0.02))
```