# Auto-assign a colour to a 3D scatterplot point based on column value in R

Tags: r, plot, colors, 3d

I have a n x 4 matrix called `db_cluster`. I want to plot the 3-D points in the matrix, and assign a color to the points based on the value in the 4th column (let's call it 'cluster') of my matrix.

Most of the info I found online manually assigns a colour to each column value (i.e if there are 3 unique data in a column, they will assign red, blue, green to each value.

I have 18 unique values in my 'cluster' column, so it is not feasible to manually assign each value to a colour. Is there a way to automatically assign a colour to a value and plot it?

Btw I'm using plot3d.

`plot3d(db_cluster)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose your data looked like this:

```r
db_cluster <- matrix(sample(10, 40, TRUE), ncol = 4)
db_cluster
#>       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#>  [1,]   10    5    6    9
#>  [2,]    4    5    4    5
#>  [3,]    5    2    9    5
#>  [4,]    9    1    5    3
#>  [5,]    8   10    3    9
#>  [6,]   10    2    2    2
#>  [7,]   10    3    3    9
#>  [8,]    8    5    2    6
#>  [9,]    9    5   10    4
#> [10,]    5    4    3    7
```

Then you could do:

```r
rgl::plot3d(x   = db_cluster[,1], 
            y   = db_cluster[,2], 
            z   = db_cluster[,3], 
            col = db_cluster[,4], size = 10)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, my data for the 'cluster' column contains numbers from 0-18. I am getting an error message

`Error in col2rgb(colors) : numerical color values must be positive`

Any idea how I can tackle this?

Comment: @zlee11 you could do `col = 1 +  db_cluster[,4]` so that there are no zero values

Comment: right, one last question - how do I add the legend to this plot?

Comment: @zlee11 see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27958226/adding-a-legend-to-an-rgl-3d-plot) , and if my answer here has helped, please consider marking it as accepted - thanks.

Comment: I've seen it before but it seems like they have manually inputted based on number of unique values. Is there a way to automatically to assign the legend? [Similar to this, except that my data is in a matrix format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34877362/add-a-legend-to-a-3d-plot-in-r)