# Doesn't work legend3d function in the newest version of the rgl package

Tags: r, rgl

I've installed the newest version of the rgl package by means of advice from the link below:
[How do I install the latest version of rgl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37142762/how-do-i-install-the-latest-version-of-rgl)
Then i tried to reproduce the code example of the answer from the post:
[Adding a legend to an rgl 3d plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27958226/adding-a-legend-to-an-rgl-3d-plot)
Everything is working Ok except the command:

```
legend3d("topright", legend = paste('Type', c('A', 'B', 'C')), pch = 16, col = rainbow(3), cex=1, inset=c(0.02))
```

After executing the above command i have the warning message and no legend on the 3dplot in fact:

```
Warning messages:
1: In rgl.material(color = color, back = back, ...) :
  RGL: Pixmap load: file format unsupported
2: In rgl.material(color = color, back = back, ...) :
  RGL: Pixmap load: failed
```

How i can fix it? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You don't have PNG support in your build.  You don't give any hint as to why...

Comment: Do you suggest my installation was incorrect? How i can know it for sure? Have i reinstall the package?  Thanks.

Comment: One possible reason i have not `zlib` on my windows mashine. During the `rgl` compilation process i caught  the error message `checking for zlib...no
  libpng requires zlib, so not installed.
  freetype requires zlib, so not installed.` Unfortunately, i can not figure out how to install `zlib' for the windows (because i'm not an advanced windows user). Could you advice me please?

Answer (score 2):

From the comments, it appears you don't have zlib in a place where R (or the rgl configure script) can see it.  The location for it is currently given in the LOCAL_SOFT variable in R_HOME/etc/<ARCH>/Makeconf.

What you put there depends on which R version you're using.  For 3.2.x or 3.3.x, I believe you can get suitable contents from https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/windows/extsoft/.