# legend3d failed in RGL : "Pixmap load: file format unsupported"

Tags: r, 3d, legend, rgl, pixmap

I’m using rgl package to draw a 3D scatterplot in R. Everything is working fine, except the legend that does not appear on the 3D plot, and I have this warning:

`Warning messages:
1: In rgl.material(color = color, back = back, ...) :
  RGL: Pixmap load: file format unsupported
2: In rgl.material(color = color, back = back, ...) :
  RGL: Pixmap load: failed`

An exemple for the command lines:

```
#if needed: install.packages("rgl")
library(rgl)
pca<-data.frame(replicate(10,sample(0:50,1000,rep=TRUE)))
mygroups <- as.factor(pca$X10) 

acp3d<-function(pca, comp=1:3, group=mygroups, plotVars = FALSE, 
            pointSize=2, plotText=FALSE){
x<-pca
hashCol<-rainbow(nlevels(group))
names(hashCol)<-levels(group)
colors<-hashCol[group]
percentVar <- pca$percentVar
plot3d(x[,comp[1]],x[,comp[2]],x[,comp[3]],
     xlab=paste0("PC",comp[1],": ",round(percentVar[comp[1]] * 100),"% variance"), 
     ylab=paste0("PC",comp[2],": ",round(percentVar[comp[2]] * 100),"% variance"), 
     zlab=paste0("PC",comp[3],": ",round(percentVar[comp[3]] * 100),"% variance"),
     col=colors,size=5,type=ifelse(plotText,"n","p"),box = FALSE)

legend3d("topright", legend = names(hashCol), pch = 16, col = hashCol, cex=1, inset=c(0.02))
}
acp3d(pca)
```

Someone had the same issue than me ([Doesn't work legend3d function in the newest version of the rgl package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37823863/doesnt-work-legend3d-function-in-the-newest-version-of-the-rgl-package)), so I tried to install zlib as recommanded. I downloaded zlib-1.2.11 and I put the folder in C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.1\library but it did not resolve my issue.
I also installed zlibbioc through biocLite, but no improvement either.
As recommanded by the answer, I also looked in C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.1/etc/x64/Makeconf, but the only thing I found about zlib in it was:

```
## For use in packages
GRAPHAPP_LIB = -lRgraphapp
TCL_VERSION = 86
# was a reference to Rzlib.dll in R < 3.2.0
ZLIB_LIBS = -lz
```

I don’t understand what it means (I am not a computer expert). I am not even sure zlib is the issue since I did not have a warning about zlib when I installed rgl.

Any idea to make the legend appears? Thanks

R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30) -- "Single Candle"
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
install.packages("rgl")

Comment: It would be easier and helpful to create a producible example by adding some sample data.

Comment: Sorry about that. I edited my post and put a producible example

Comment: You should only need zlib if you are building rgl from source.  If you are running `install.packages("rgl")` on Windows, you aren't doing that, it would have been built on CRAN.  I just tried that on R 3.4.1 and 3.4.2 and your code ran without error.  Perhaps you have a bad build of R?  Did you get it from CRAN, or from Microsoft?  Theirs are known to contain errors.

Comment: @user2554330. I updated R and reinstalled the rgl package and indeed, it worked. Thanks!

Comment: I just tried Microsoft's build of R, and didn't see the error there, either.  So I haven't any idea what went wrong for you.  Hope it doesn't come back!