# rgl fade with depth, depth perception

Tags: r, rgl

How can I show objects further away with a fade-out effect in rgl?

Currently, given a 3D scatter plot, R's rgl package displays objects further away with a smaller size. However, I still find it difficult to perceive an object's depth, especially when many points are plotted. In the following example, without rotating, it is hard to see which point is behind another.

```
x <- 1:101
y <- rnorm(101, sd=15)
z <- x + rnorm(101, sd=15)
library(rgl)
plot3d(x,y,z, type='s')
```

But in the image below, it is easy to see that points on the left of the picture are further away. How can I achieve a similar effect in rgl? There is an `alpha` argument, but that does not depend on the depth of each point.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenGL supports "fog", and `rgl` gives you some control over it, though it's not completely obvious how to get it.  However, this works if you run it before most functions:

```
r3dDefaults$material$fog <- TRUE
r3dDefaults$bg$fogtype <- "linear"
```

If you want some parts of your display to fade out and others not, set the material for the non-fogged parts with `fog = FALSE`.   This is normally the default.

The choices for fog type are `c("none", "linear", "exp", "exp2")`.  With linear fog, your example looks like this:

[image: screenshot]

If you want to have the fog only affecting the points, you could do it like this:

```
r3dDefaults$material$fog <- FALSE
r3dDefaults$bg$fogtype <- "linear"
plot3d(x, y, z, type = "s", fog = TRUE)
```

This works because material properties are only applied to the data, not the axes.  I think this version looks better, but your taste may vary:

[image]

One limitation:  fog is not currently supported by the WebGL code produced by `rglwidget()`.

**Edit:**  It was noted in the comments that calling `bgplot3d` clears the fog.  This was a bug in `rgl` versions up to 0.100.33, that has been fixed as of 0.100.34.  See [How do I install the latest version of rgl?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37142762/2554330) for where to get it.

**Edit 2:**  The development version of `rgl` (currently 0.102.4) now supports fog in WebGL as well as in R.  The display is a little different for `fogtype = "exp"` and `fogtype = "exp2"`; I think it actually looks better.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for :)

Comment: If I would like to include a title to the plot, as per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33425187/8696224), how should I modify your example? A simple `plot3d(..., fog=TRUE)` followed by `bgplot3d({plot.new() })` does not have the fog present

Comment: Looks like a bug.  I think you'll need to fix `bgplot3d` to allow it to pass `fogtype = "linear")` to `bg3d` along with the other arguments it passes.

Answer (score 1):

How about generate a new variable for `alpha`:

```
x <- 1:101
y <- rnorm(101, sd=5)
z <- x + rnorm(101, sd=15)
a <-11/(order(z) +10)
library(rgl)
plot3d(x, y, z, type = 's', 
       alpha = a)
```

You may want to adjust those values in `a <- 11/(order(z) + 10` to get the look you like.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but does it work when I rotate the plot?